# C++ Quantlib Swap Payment Dates

Tags: c++, swap, quantlib

When I use Quantlib to price vanilla interest rate swap, the payment dates for each cash flows are always the same as the accrual period end dates. Here is the way I normally use to set up a vanilla swap:

```
Schedule fixedSchedule(previousResetDate, maturity, 6 * Months, NullCalendar(), ModifiedFollowing, ModifiedFollowing, DateGeneration::Backward, false);
Schedule floatSchedule(previousResetDate, maturity, 3 * Months, NullCalendar(), ModifiedFollowing, ModifiedFollowing, DateGeneration::Backward, false);
VanillaSwap swap(VanillaSwap::Receiver, nominal, fixedSchedule, fixedRate, Thirty360(), floatSchedule, libor, spread, Actual360());
```

In practice, there are some swaps may have payment dates different from the accrual period end dates. For example, 2 days after the accrual end date and then apply business day convention adjustment. I just wonder is it possible to set the payment dates in this way in Quantlib?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, at this time there's no way to get the behavior you want.  I guess it will require adding the relevant code to the `FixedRateLeg` and `IborLeg` classes, since that's where the schedule is taken apart and the coupons are created.

Answer (score 0):

You can always give your own payment dates like:

```
    Schedule(std::vector<Date> { Date(1, Jan, 2016 }, Date(1, Jan, 2017 } });
```

The constructor that does that is:

```
    Schedule(const std::vector<Date>&,
             const Calendar& calendar = NullCalendar(),
             const BusinessDayConvention
                                convention = Unadjusted,
             boost::optional<BusinessDayConvention>
                 terminationDateConvention = boost::none,
             const boost::optional<Period> tenor = boost::none,
             boost::optional<DateGeneration::Rule> rule = boost::none,
             boost::optional<bool> endOfMonth = boost::none,
             const std::vector<bool>& isRegular = std::vector<bool>(0));
```

Comment: Thanks for your seuggestion. I tried this constructor by passing a payment date vector to Schedule. However, it seems Quantlib just uses this vector as cash flow dates as well as accrual start and end dates. Hence, the problem is not resolved. Is there any way I can separate the accrual end date with the payment date by, say 2 business dayss?